# Is there a new library for Java that supports IPv6 on Solaris?

Tags: java, dns, ipv6

I'm doing the following to lookup an Internet address.  It fails specifically on Solaris machines that have IPv6 nameservers in the resolv.conf.  Works fine on Windows machines that have IPv6 nameservers and on IPv4 only Solaris machines.  From the error returned it appears that the Java "getAttributes" line is failing internally (somewhere deep) with a parsing problem when presented with an IPv6 nameserver.  My question is, "is there a way to do this better that works properly on Solaris when IPv6 is in use?"

```
InetAddress localhost=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
ipAddress=localhost.getHostAddress();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext(env);
Attributes attrs=ictx.getAttributes("blah.test.fakedomain", new String[] { "A" });
```

Comment: What information are you trying to obtain? I've never seen that usage of the naming API before

Comment: What I'm doing is retrieving the A records for a given host name.  I need a list of all the IP addresses for a certain domain name.  However, the Java library itself fails deep inside if on a Solaris host running IPv6 nameservers.  Perhaps there's a different way to do it that won't fail in that situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Java work "better".  No longer fails internally like this after upgrading to Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

The base [java.net.InetAddress](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) has had [IPv6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) variants and [IPv4](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html) variants since Java 1.4 (per the javadoc).

Sounds like you've got more of a question about com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory.  What version of Java?

Comment: This is J2SE6.  Unfortunately, I don't know ahead of time if the machine will be using IPv6 or IPv4 nameservers.  Hence the whole point of using the Java library and not rolling my own.  :-)